# Why does filter not return the result of predicate function?

Tags: clojure

I am starting to learn Clojure, but I don't understand why the below code doesn't works as expected.

Given a string, I want it to print all words longer than 2 characters with the first letter capitalized.

Expected output: `("Fine" "Day")`
Actual output: `("fine" "day")`

```
(ns exploring
    (:require [clojure.contrib.string :as str]))

(defn a-function [word]
    "Capitaliza todas palavras maiores que 2 chars"
    (if (>(count word ) 2) (str/capitalize word)))

(use '[clojure.contrib.str-utils :only (re-split)])
(filter a-function (re-split #"\W+" "A fine day it is"))
```

Comment: Oh shit, here the code https://gist.github.com/1908802

Answer (score 3):

I would use map in addition to filter:

```
(ns exploring
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
  (:use '[clojure.contrib.str-utils :only (re-split)])

(def a-function
  [word]
  (> (count word) 2))

(map str/capitalize
     (filter a-function
             (re-split #"\W+" "A fine day it is")))
```

Comment: Because `filter` produces a seq containing the elements of the *original* seq for which the predicate (`a-function`) returns true. So your solution will not produce capitalized results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keep` with  your original `a-function`:

```
(keep a-function (re-split #"\W+" "A fine day it is"))
```

Comment: Why? In this case that will only result in (false true true false false).

Comment: Yes, using your modified predicate of `a-function` would produce a seq of booleans. But I'm referring to the _original definition_ by @user428691: `(defn a-function [word] (if (>(count word ) 2) (str/capitalize word)))`.

Answer (score 0):

If the order in which the capitalized words are returned is not important you can also do:

```
(reduce #(if (> (count %2) 2) (cons (str/capitalize %2) %) %) nil (re-split #"\W+" "A fine day it is"))
```

Resulting in ("Day" "Fine")

I'm not claiming this is better, just another way to solve the same problem.